# Hibernate id generate strategy sequence does not working

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have entity with `SEQUENCE` id generation strategy. But on saving the entity to the database it is assigned a negative id. And my sequence is ignored. I check the sequence current value in database -  it does not change.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dealers")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Dealer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dealers_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "dealers_id_seq", sequenceName = "dealers_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}
```

gradle dependencies:

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'java'

        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE'
        }
    }
dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'

        //jpa
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.4.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
        compile 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.4.3'

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `allocationSize` to `@SequenceGenerator`

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "dealers_id_seq", sequenceName = "dealers_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
```